# I need to create third party flask rest api where api should be protected from outside access without user login credentials

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Im creating rest apis in flask.
This apis are used by another application. users will login to application and calls our third party apis. But the question is how to secure the apis from users who are not loggedin to application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OAuth2.0 to secure your rest apis. The applications who are granted access will only be able to access those resources. It is a good and standard way of securing RESTful web services. 
Have a look at [Flask-OAuthlib](https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html)

Comment: The problem is as we are creating third party apis we dont store any user information.

Comment: I think OAuth will solve that as well because you can redirect the user to Authenticate with a provider like Github, Facebook, Google or any other 3rd party that provides OAuth authentication.

Comment: I think your are confused. The user will login to Application and login credential will be stored there. That application will call apis created in different flask application. For this flask application we are not capturing any user data or we dont have access to it. But we need to provide security for flask apis.

Comment: If you dont store anything, dont authenticate, dont authorize (grant etc), dont get someone else to authenticate, I dont see how your code will come to know the request is coming from a 3rd party application it is supposed to respond to. You can though have a registry (similar to oauth implementation) of all the apps that you want to access the apis but then it goes against your assumption of storing anything.